# Knights of the Lambda Calculus infinity written as lisp code

Tags: lambda, lisp, lambda-calculus, infinity, y-combinator

Knights of the Lambda Calculus logo have infinity written as `(Y F) = (F (Y F))`

[image: Knights of the Lambda Calculus logo]

is this lisp code the same and is it represent infinity too?

(Y (λ (F) (Y F)))

Comment: in your code, you show `Y` used but not defined. What is its definition?

Comment: @WillNess it's Y Combinator.

Comment: and what is its definition please? do you mean it's the same as in `Y F = F (Y F)`? Because *that* is not a lambda expression, and you use it inside a lambda expression. Lambda calculus has no definitions, that's why they use capital letter Y to mean it should be substituted with a lambda expression *for* Y. That also means you shouldn't use capital `F` there, but a regular `f`.

Comment: Look at scheme implementation in Rosetta Code in @dsm answer. And my code is not lambda calculus it's lisp code `λ` can be written as `lambda`.

Comment: @WillNess I didn't define `Y` because it's well known the same as if I write `(! 10)` and didn't define factorial function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by eta contraction your expression `Y (λ f. Y f)` is `Y Y`. Since `Y f` reduces to `f (Y f)`, we get

```
Y Y --> Y (Y Y) --> Y Y (Y (Y Y)) --> Y (Y Y) (Y (Y Y)) --> ...
```

so it is a divergent lambda term.

`Y f` is not a divergent term in itself. It reduces to `f (Y f)`, where `f` now takes over. If `f` ever uses its argument, and is forced to do so by *its* caller, only *then* the chain will continue.

Answer (score 3):

*Y* here is a [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). Given a function *f*, it returns a value *x* for which *x = f(x)*.  When, instead of writing *x*, we write *Y(f)*, we have *Y(f) = f(Y(f))*.  In the traditional lambda calculus notation, this is *(F (Y F)) = (Y F)*, which is what you see in the image.

Some numerical functions have one or more fixed points.  E.g., fixed point of the (positive) square root function, as well as the square function are 1 and 0..  Some numerical functions, e.g., *f(x) → x+1* doesn't have a fixed point. In some formalisms, including the untyped lambda calculus, *every* function has a fixed point.

This particular fixed-point operator is the Y-combinator, and is described in more detail in various places, including the Wikipedia article linked above.  Fixed point operators are important because, among other things, they allow recursive functions to be defined in formalisms such as the untyped lambda calculus.

Answer (score 1):

This equation of the `y-combinator` actually can be derived via 4-5 reductions starting from this equation, which is also called the `canonical combinator`,

```
((lambda (self) (self self)) (lambda (self) (self self)))
```

To see a concrete result of this infinite recursion one needs to insert a final criterion for the recursion, for example in this kind of primitive-recursive equation:

```
((lambda(s) (s s 100))
 (lambda(s n)
   (if (zero? n)
     0
     (+ n (s s (- n 1))))))

;Value: 5050
```

The picture actually represents either the y-combinator or merely this canonical combinator.

This picture was drawn at MIT by implementing an embedded programming language in scheme that had pictures as atomic objects and simple ways to combine pictures, [see here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps4hnd/readme.html) .

And [at this link](https://shashi.github.io/ijulia-notebooks/funcgeo/) is a detailed description of the functional geometry language of the computer scientist `Peter Henderson` who tried to create a programming language to generate the pictures of Escher and was also used to generate the logo of MIT-SCHEME: